# python: how to turn my enumerated string into a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to send the output of my string enumerator into a dictionary to include both the output of the enumerator and its index...

I've got this as a basis:

```
>>> dictionary = dict()
>>> for i, c in enumerate('My Great String'):
...   print("c"+str(i),c)
...
c0 M
c1 y
c2
c3 G
c4 r
c5 e
c6 a
c7 t
c8
c9 S
c10 t
c11 r
c12 i
c13 n
c14 g
```

It's the right track. But I'd like to output each 'element' like this:

```
dictionary['c0'] = 'M'
dictionary['c1'] = 'y'
dictionary['c2'] = ''
... (etc)
```

Comment: Use a dictionary comprehension

Comment: If having integer keys instead of using `c0`, `c1`, etc. is fine, you can do `dict(enumerate('My Great String'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign each value to the dictionary using the respective key:

#### Code

```
dictionary = dict()
for i, c in enumerate('My Great String'):
    dictionary['c%d' % i] = c

print(dictionary)
```

You can use a **dictionary comprehension** like this:

#### Code

```
dictionary = {'c%d' % i: c for i, c in enumerate('My Great String')}

print(dictionary)
```

#### Output

```
{'c0': 'M', 'c1': 'y', 'c2': ' ', 'c3': 'G', 'c4': 'r', 'c5': 'e', 'c6': 'a', 'c7': 't', 'c8': ' ', 'c9': 'S', 'c10': 't', 'c11': 'r', 'c12': 'i', 'c13': 'n', 'c14': 'g'}
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is more info about dictionaries and *dict comprehensions* on official documentation

Comment: Considering this question is tagged `python-3.x`, `.format` or f-strings are prefered.

Comment: Guys - (I know I'm not supposed to say 'thanks', but 'Thanks!' - both of these suggestions work like a charm! Now, can you suggest how to massage that syntax into a add_to_dictionary syntax?

Comment: @DrLou I just edited my answer to show you how you could build the dictionary on demand, like you said: _add-to-dictionary syntax_. Please, if that change is what you need, mark my answer as **accepted** (green checkmark). Thanks in advance!

Comment: These answers are _both_ so excellent, it's impossible to contain my exuberance. @DYZ's response was precisely on-point (to my not-very-well-worded question), while the add-to-dict is really what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary comprehension is an option:

```
{"c{}".format(i): c for i, c in enumerate('My Great String')}
```